# SSL cert issue with Python Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl

I'm making a request to a site which requires SSL cert to access.
When I tried to access the URL, I get SSL Certificate error

```
import requests
proxies = {"https":"https://user:pwd@host:port"}
r = requests.get("https://URL", proxies=proxies)
print(r.status_code)
```

> File "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
>       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
>     File "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
>       raise SSLError(e, request=request)
>   requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pit-wvrpnpd.johnlewis.co.uk', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /suite-api (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)')))

If I use verify=False in Python's Requests, I'm getting below error

```
r = requests.get("https://URL", proxies=proxies,verify=False)
```

> C:\Program Files\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
>     InsecureRequestWarning)
>   403

So I decided to download the SSL certificate from Chrome "site.cer"
Then I used it as below, yet it throws error

```
r = requests.get("https://URL", proxies=proxies, cert=('C:\\site.cer'))
```

> File "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
>       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
>     File "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
>       raise SSLError(e, request=request)
>   requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pit-wvrpnpd.johnlewis.co.uk', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /suite-api (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(9, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3854)')))

I'm using Python 3.7, any Idea where I made a mistake?

Comment: Note that what you got with `verify=False` is **not** an error. Is just a warning telling you that you *probably* don't want to use `verify=False`. The issue is that the website is using a self-signed certificate produced by a CA that you don't trust. Note that [the option to use for server certificate validation is `verify`](https://2.python-requests.org//en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification). The `cert` option is used to provide a **client** certificate (which is used to authenticate the client to the server, but your error is the client not verified the server).

Comment: Something wrong with certificate. But `cert` param used for self signing requests, it won't solve your problem. Take a look on `verify`.

Comment: Note that after disabling server cert verification, you got a 403 status code. The server denied your request. That has nothing to do with TLS/SSL.

Comment: Any Idea what's the next step to take on this?

Comment: The URL works fine in browser, but fails in code

Answer (score 7):

Adding this header with `verify=False` gave me access.

```py
headers = {
    'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36",
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/index.htm"
req = requests.get(url,verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
print(soup.title)
```

#THIS WORKS

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).