# VS Code Python - Calling HTTPS endpoint - SSL Error

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, visual-studio-code

There are different variants of this question in SF but I am not finding a solution to fix my issue.

Issue - I am running VSCode, Anaconda 3.8.5 with Conda on Windows 10 to run my python code to make a connection with Azure Log Analytics to write some custom logs. I am getting the below error and I have tried a couple of options to fix the issue but none of them seem to fix the issue. Not really sure even though I have the openssl I keep getting the error module not found. Reference Links - ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58011158/ssl-cert-issue-with-python-requests), [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404000/problems-with-proxy-in-vscode))

SSL Error:    `HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxx.ods.opinsights.azure.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/logs?api-version=2016-04-01 (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))`

What I have tried with no luck:

1. I reinstalled the openssl library in my conda environment and I got the latest version 1.1.1j and restarted my conda and VS Code.
2. Disabling the SSL in the code using Ignore=False in the requests.post call as per some of the suggestions in SF
3. Tried disabling "http.proxyStrictSSL": false in the VSCode settings.json file.

Is there anything else I could try to fix the issue?

Comment: *"Disabling the SSL in the code using Ignore=False .."* - this does not disable SSL. This only disables the verification of the certificate. *"http.proxyStrictSSL"* - this is unrelated to your problem either. The problem is that the SSL module cannot be loaded in the first place.

Comment: *"I reinstalled the openssl library in my conda environment and I got the latest version 1.1.1j and restarted my conda and VS Code."* - Python must be actually linked to this library, i.e. just "reinstalling" it is not enough. What happens if you do a simple `import ssl` using Python inside VS but also outside?

Comment: I tried this earlier and getting the Module not found error. As indicated in my question, I do have the openssl under my conda environment so not sure what's missing.

Comment: Again, just having openssl is not sufficient but it must be actually be linked into Python. Note that there are several hits when google'ing for "conda windows 10 ssl not available" and the first one I get might actually point out the [cause behind your problem](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8273#issuecomment-511200205): *".. the only ways I know of to get into trouble now is by installing 3rd party software that puts incompatible dlls in system directories and also having used conda init for a different install location."*.

Comment: Thanks very much @SteffenUllrich. Though I installed openssl in my conda in the DLL folders under that environment these two files were missing for some reason - libssl and libcrypto. Once I manually copied the files into the DLL folder, the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documenting the answer as it might help someone else.
Issue: My conda environment for some reason didn't have the necessary dlls libssl and libcrypto in the path 'C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\envs\db\DLLs'.

Solution: Under my anaconda installation I could find the dlls in the correct path so I copied them over to my conda environment and that fixed the issue with the opensll library. Thanks to @SteffenUllrich for pointing to me an article which kind of hinted this solution.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to copy these files from Anaconda3/Library/bin to Anaconda3/DLLs :

libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll

libssl-1_1-x64.dll